# Why is it considered poor practice to use Axios or HTTP calls in components?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

[In this article](https://alligator.io/vuejs/rest-api-axios/), it says:

> While it’s generally poor practice, you can use Axios directly in your components to fetch data from a method, lifecycle hook, or whenever.

I am wondering why? I usually use lifecycle hooks a lot to fetch data (especially from `created()`). Where should we write the request calls?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Writing `API` methods directly in components increases code lines and make difficult to read.
As far as I believe the `author` is suggesting to separate `API` methods into a `Service`.

Let's take a case where you have to fetch `top posts` and operate on data. If you do that in component it is not re-usable, you have to duplicate it in other components where ever you want to use it.

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    top: [],
    errors: []
  }),

  // Fetches posts when the component is created.
  created() {
    axios.get(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/top`)
    .then(response => {
      // flattening the response
      this.top = response.data.map(item => {
         title: item.title,
         timestamp: item.timestamp,
         author: item.author
      })
    })
    .catch(e => {
      this.errors.push(e)
    })

  }
}
```

So when you need to fetch `top post` in another component you have to duplicate the code.

Now let's put `API methods` in a `Service`.

```
api.js file

const fetchTopPosts = function() {
  return axios.get(`http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/top`)
        .then(response => {
          // flattening the response
          this.top = response.data.map(item => {
             title: item.title,
             timestamp: item.timestamp,
             author: item.author
          })
        }) // you can also make a chain.
}

export default {
   fetchTopPosts: fetchTopPosts
}
```

So you use the above `API methods` in any components you wish.

After this:

```
import API from 'path_to_api.js_file'
export default {
      data: () => ({
        top: [],
        errors: []
      }),

      // Fetches posts when the component is created.
      created() {
         API.fetchTopPosts().then(top => {
            this.top = top
         })
         .catch(e => {
          this.errors.push(e)
         })

      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I understand now.

Comment: Someone also wrote an interesting article about this: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/08/28/vue-js-ajax-recipes/

Comment: This is fine but often the URL /Params of the Ajax call depend upon some data from the VUE instance /component such as current Route/selected items in a list etc and the seperate api.js file won't have access to the vue instance and I would end up passing too many params. What do suggest in this case?

Comment: @SainathS.R call function with arguments from the store

Answer (score 7):

It's fine for small apps or widgets, but in a real SPA, it's better to abstract away your API into its own module, and if you use vuex, to use actions to call that api module.

Your component should not be concerned with *how* and *from where* its data is coming. The component is responsible for UI, not AJAX.

```
import api from './api.js'

created() {
  api.getUsers().then( users => {
    this.users = users
  })
}

// vs.

created() {
  axios.get('/users').then({ data }=> {
    this.users = data
  })
}
```

In the above example, your "axios-free" code is not really much shorter, but imagine what you could potentially keep out of the component:

- handling HTTP errors, e.g. retrying
- pre-formatting data from the server so it fits your component
- header configuration (content-type, access token ...)
- creating `FormData` for POSTing e.g. image files

the list can get long. all of that doesn't belong into the component because it has nothing to do with the view. The view only needs the resulting data or error message.

It also means that you can test your components and api independently.

Comment: Question for you: In part 3 of this article (https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/08/28/vue-js-ajax-recipes/) the author discusses combining both state and AJAX logic in the Vuex store. He says it's a good idea to return a promise from your actions so you can react to the resolution of the request -- is that scenario being assumed in your "axios-free" code above?